# Unable to access values in nested dictionary for adding link in network

Tags: python, dictionary, mininet

I have the following dictionary

> **d={'s1': {'s2': {}, 's3': {}, 's4': {}}, 's2': {'s5': {'bw': 20, 'delay': '1ms'}}, 's3': {'s6': {'bw': 20, 'delay': '1ms'}}, 's4': {'s7': {'bw': 20, 'delay': '1ms'}}, 's5': {'h1': {'bw': 10, 'delay': '5ms'}, 'h2': {'bw': 10, 'delay': '5ms'}}, 's6': {'h3': {'bw': 10, 'delay': '5ms'}, 'h4': {'bw': 10, 'delay': '5ms'}}, 's7': {'h5': {'bw': 10, 'delay': '5ms'}, 'h6': {'bw': 10, 'delay': '5ms'}}}**

I would like to access the values of bw and delay for link. For ex- I want `addLink(s7,h6,bw=10,delay=5ms)` to work.

I am using following code for it
#!/usr/bin/python

```
import yaml
#from ruamel import yaml
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import Controller, RemoteController, OVSController
from mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.log import setLogLevel, info
from mininet.link import TCLink
def myNetwork():

# Create an instance of Mininet class i.e. the network with default values
net = Mininet(autoStaticArp=True, autoSetMacs=True)

a_yaml_file = open("Complex_Topology.yaml")
parsed_yaml_file = yaml.load(a_yaml_file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
parsed_yaml_file["Controllers"]
parsed_yaml_file["Hosts"]
print(parsed_yaml_file["Links"])
parsed_yaml_file["Switches"]

for i in parsed_yaml_file["Controllers"]:
    net.addController(i)
for i in parsed_yaml_file["Hosts"]:
    net.addHost(i)
for i in parsed_yaml_file["Switches"]:
    net.addSwitch(i) 
d=parsed_yaml_file["Links"]
def freeze(x):
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        return frozenset(freeze(items) for items in x.items())
    elif isinstance(x, list):
        return tuple(freeze(value) for value in x)
    return x

for i in d.keys():
    for j in d[i].keys():
        k=freeze(d[i].values) 
        net.addLink(i,j,k)
info( '*** Starting network\n')
net.start()
# Start the Mininet CLI to run commands
CLI(net)
# Stop the network
net.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setLogLevel( 'info' )
    myNetwork()
```

I am getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "new.py", line 83, in <module>
myNetwork()
File "new.py", line 73, in myNetwork
net.addLink(i,j,k)
File "/home/sudhanshu/Desktop/SDN/mininet/net.py", line 400, in addLink
link = cls( node1, node2, **options )
File "/home/sudhanshu/Desktop/SDN/mininet/link.py", line 450, in __init__
self.makeIntfPair( intfName1, intfName2, addr1, addr2,
File "/home/sudhanshu/Desktop/SDN/mininet/link.py", line 495, in makeIntfPair
return makeIntfPair( intfname1, intfname2, addr1, addr2, node1, node2,
File "/home/sudhanshu/Desktop/SDN/mininet/util.py", line 266, in makeIntfPair
raise Exception( "Error creating interface pair (%s,%s): %s " %
Exception: Error creating interface pair (s1-eth<built-in method values of dict object at 0x7f1f6b6035c0>,s2-eth1): bash: built-in: No such file or directory
```

I have tried manipulating my code but failed.

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: `k=freeze(d[i].values)` You forgot the parentheses on the end of the `.values()` function.  Instead, you're actually referring to the values _function object_.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But I am still getting error-Exception: Error creating interface pair (s1-ethdict_values([{}, {}, {}]),s2-eth1): bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: bash?  this code calls bash?  you'll have to show us that part of the code.

Comment: code is very long for comment. How can I show it to you.

Comment: Don't put the code in a comment; edit the question.

Comment: Hi John. Just added the full code. I have parsed links in a dictionary from a yaml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call the method as `addLink(s7, h6, bw=10, delay=5ms)`, then you could create the links by using:

```
for i in d:
    for j in d[i]:
        net.addLink(i, j, **d[i][j])
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. It is creating the network but bandwidth and delay are not there in the link.

Comment: Note that in your input some links are missing bw and delay (e.g., s1 to s2) while others have (s7 to h5)

Comment: You are right. I have parsed a yaml file, where some links have link parameters and some doesnt. I need to build the network in One go i.e via loop.

Comment: I used following for i in d.keys():
        for j in d[i].keys():
            
            if d[i].values() is dict:
                    #k=freeze(d[i].values())
                net.addLink(i,j,**d[i][j])
            else:
                net.addLink(i,j)

Comment: I am still not getting link parameters.